# How does the LaTeX reference mechanism associate text with a label?

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, sidebar

In my LaTeX document I have created a sidebar environment that is implemented like this:

```
% Usage:
% \begin{sidebar}{title}
% text
% \end{sidebar}

\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
\global\mdfdefinestyle{exampledefault}{%
linecolor=lightgray,linewidth=1pt,%
leftmargin=1cm,rightmargin=1cm,
}

\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{mdbox}{t}{box}
\floatname{mdbox}{Sidebar}

\newenvironment{sidebar}[1]{%
\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={\tikz\node[fill=white,rectangle,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]{#1};},
frametitleaboveskip=-0.5\ht\strutbox,
frametitlealignment=\raggedright
}%
\begin{mdbox}
   \begin{mdframed}[style=exampledefault]
     \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
     \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
}{
   \end{mdframed}
 \end{mdbox}}
```

This makes lovely sidebars, like:

```
\begin{sidebar}{Lovely sidebar}
  This is a lovely sidebar.  This is a lovely sidebar.  This is a
  lovely sidebar.  This is a lovely sidebar.  This is a lovely
  sidebar.  This is a lovely sidebar.  This is a lovely sidebar.  This
  is a lovely sidebar.  This is a lovely sidebar.  This is a lovely
  sidebar.  This is a lovely sidebar.  This is a lovely sidebar.  This
  is a lovely sidebar.  This is a lovely sidebar.  This is a lovely
  sidebar.  This is a lovely sidebar.  This is a lovely sidebar.  This
  is a lovely sidebar.  This is a lovely sidebar.
  \end{sidebar}
```

[image]

I would like to stick the sidebar title into a label so that I can reference it elsewhere in the text. But I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Here I load `nameref` pacakge (which is usually auto-loaded by `hyperref`) and add `\def\@currentlabelname{#1}\NR@sanitize@labelname` at the beginning of definition of `sidebar` environment.

With these changes, you can use `\nameref` to refer to the title of a `sidebar`, if it is labeled.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{exampledefault}{
  linecolor=lightgray,
  linewidth=1pt,
  leftmargin=1cm,
  rightmargin=1cm,
}

\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{mdbox}{t}{box}
\floatname{mdbox}{Sidebar}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{sidebar}[1]{%
  \def\@currentlabelname{#1}%
  \NR@sanitize@labelname
  \mdfsetup{%
    frametitle={\tikz\node[fill=white,rectangle,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]{#1};},
    frametitleaboveskip=-0.5\ht\strutbox,
    frametitlealignment=\raggedright
  }%
\begin{mdbox}
   \begin{mdframed}[style=exampledefault]
     \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
     \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
}{
   \end{mdframed}
 \end{mdbox}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

See sidebar \ref{key} on page \pageref{key} with title ``\nameref{key}''.

\begin{sidebar}{Lovely sidebar}\label{key}
  This is a lovely sidebar.  This is a lovely sidebar.  This is a
  lovely sidebar.  This is a lovely sidebar.  This is a lovely
  sidebar.  This is a lovely sidebar.  This is a lovely sidebar.  This
  is a lovely sidebar.  This is a lovely sidebar.  This is a lovely
  sidebar.  This is a lovely sidebar.  This is a lovely sidebar.  This
  is a lovely sidebar.  This is a lovely sidebar.  This is a lovely
  sidebar.  This is a lovely sidebar.  This is a lovely sidebar.  This
  is a lovely sidebar.  This is a lovely sidebar.
\end{sidebar}

\end{document}
```

[image]